# How to loop a linear CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate a list of html elements with following CSS property:

```
animation: slide-right 10s linear infinite 0s;
```

Animation is perfect for me but, when list finish I would like to have a loop behaviour instead of a jerky transition that restart the animation because of infinite property of animation.

I tried to workaround it appending items via jQuery but it doesn't work. It's possible to do a loop animation with css3?

I got inspiration from this codepen: https://codepen.io/goomy/pen/vXKGGz

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** [My code here](https://codepen.io/lupin0734/pen/gRERpK)

Comment: you need to post the complete code that makes up the animation (HTML and CSS), otherwise there is no way to help you.

Comment: @Johannes you are right sorry. This is my code: https://codepen.io/lupin0734/pen/gRERpK

Comment: Your CodePen doesn't work because you have not defined the `slide-left` animation in your CSS.

Comment: @BenElliott now my codepen works .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

By "loop" I am going to assume you mean you want the element to re-appear from the bottom of the screen once it has vanished off the top of the screen.

One way to achieve this could be to set `overflow-y: hidden` on your `body` element, and then define the animation keyframes in terms of viewport height units, `vh`. If you translate an element to appear at `y = 110vh` then (assuming the document doesn't overflow) you know that it must appear off-screen since the very bottom of the body element is at `100vh`. Similarly, you can transition to something like `-10vh` at the top, assuming the element is less than `10vh` tall.

I modified your CodePen to illustrate this idea:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwBxPL